# ActivityManager : Reason: Input dispatching timed out

Tags: android, android-activity

I am starting an activity through Explicit intent with some data in the bundle when target activity started i am getting the data.

If the intent is null,or bundle data is null i am finishing the target activity.
This is what iam doing in onCreate.

I got below exception and my app got crash.
Why and when this exception occurs ?

```
07-10 10:57:05.459: E/ActivityManager(1008): Reason: Input dispatching timed out 
(Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may 
eventually     add a window when it finishes starting up.)
```